# How do I implement gradual engagement using Devise and Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to implement a delayed-signup (aka delayed authentication aka gradual engagement) website flow using Devise + Rails.

By **[gradual engagement](http://blog.henriquez.net/2009/08/kill-your-signup-form-with-rails.html)**, I mean

> "Don't make the user sign in until she
>   absolutely has to, but let her play
>   around and be remembered on the site"

I'm looking for a simple way to do this using **devise**. I feel like this is something many others have had to do, but I haven't found documentation on it.

The following approach sounds ok in my head, so I'm going to start with it:

> 1. Create users that are only "rememberable"
> 2. When certain pages are accessed, require that these users have more
>      data on them, like a username and
>      password, via something like
>      "before_filter :authenticate_user!" in
>      the appropriate controllers.

Does this approach make sense? Is there a better one? Do you have an implementation of a gradual engagement approach to signup/registration forms using Devise + Rails that you're willing to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point of the article you gave us is to say:

- only ask for sign up if necessary.

What does this mean?

Let's take an example. You're an e-commerce web site.

When does the customer has to sign up "at last"? During checkout. Never before. So you don't have to store, or remember anything about the user. **Devise is never, never used here.**

How do you manage the shopping cart of an unsigned in/up user? I'd say database, with session Id as primary key. Or You could store all the items ids in cookie, for later use.

In your code, if you have an action called `checkout`, just set in your controller a `before_filter authenticate_user!, :only => [:checkout]`

But maybe you have some constraints, like being able to keep your user's nickname without signing him up for example?

Comment: be careful with storing to much information in cookies, sometimes it can cause security breach: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html

Answer (score 1):

One alternate option is to do email-only signup, then send an email with a special link to finish registration later / bring them back to their account. There's an actively maintained tutorial on devise email-only signup at:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up

I've used this tutorial for a site I did a while back where we only asked for their email address to sign up, then later sent emails for them to complete registration / add a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep all unsigned user's data in cookies, and transfer them to database once the user logs in, if you need to.

Comment: This is not a very detailed answer Mirko... what method should I use, then? I'm trying to do this through Devise's structure. (this has occurred to me and I'm still struggling with how to do it)

Comment: I think Pasta gave a thorough answer

Comment: For anyone reading this and considering this approach, a word of caution. If you allow the client to supply details in a cookie (ie user id) which you then use server side to authenticate that user you need someway of ensuring they didn't just change the details. For example, userid 1 may be yourself as an admin. If you stash a userid in the cookie and then use that to decide what the user sees on the server then userid 2 can trivially change their cookie to userid 1 and become you.